# Omitting end of the result found from a regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have this regular expression in c#:

```
Regex oRegex_ = new Regex("<!-- #BeginEditable \"Body\"[^>]*>(.*)<!-- #EndEditable [^>]*>", RegexOptions.Multiline);
MatchCollection matches_ = oRegex_.Matches(contents);
```

The variable called 'contents' equals this:

```
<!-- #BeginEditable "Body" -->First String<!-- #EndEditable --><!-- #BeginEditable "Extra" -->Second String<!-- #EndEditable -->
```

Currently it doesnt seem to grab what i need, which is

```
'First String'
```

Instead it grabs

```
'First String<!-- #EndEditable --><!-- #BeginEditable "Extra" -->Second String<!-- #EndEditable -->'
```

Can anyone help me solve this using a regular expression? :(

Please Note: i will be replacing 'Body' to become a variable and then put it all in a loop so i can extract 'Second String' by making the variable equal 'Extra'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a non greedy catch using `*?`:

```
<!-- #BeginEditable \"Body\"[^>]*>(.*?)<!-- #EndEditable [^>]*>
```

Another option is to catch the right character (not `<`, but this is less accurate if you allow `<`s in your body):

```
<!-- #BeginEditable \"Body\"[^>]*>([^<]*)<!-- #EndEditable [^>]*>
```

Comment: Excellent that did the trick! Thank you a million times over! You saved me from extreme depression!

Comment: Great! Because you have to watch over your health. That's what's really important :) . Happy to help.